# Как сделать анимацию блока с изображением при наведении?

Tags: css3, html5

Как сделать анимацию блока с изображением при наведении?

Анимируется только блок с изображением, остальная часть должна быть сверху на нижним блоком.

Сейчас происходит сдвиг

Код - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/276hqock/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 15px;
}

.item {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 2% 0;
}

.item-pict {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: height .3s ease;
}

.item-pict>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item-content {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.item:hover .item-pict {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 15px;
}

.item {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 2% 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.item-pict {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.item-pict>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item-content {
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.item:hover .item-pict {
  height: 200px;
}

.item:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-pict">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/480/any" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```